# Set limit to div in scrollable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok lets see if I can describe my problem in an understandable way.
Im building a schedule with an user column to the left and a timeline to the right.
The timeline holds schedule events. Each event holds a title. The timeline is scrollable in both directions.
When I scroll horizontally the events is slided underneath the user column, which they are supposed to do.

But, I would like to have the event title floating and still shown until the whole event is completely slided under. In other words, I want the user to always be able to se the event title regardless of how long the event is (as long as the event is visible).

I cant fix the title div on an specific position due to the both X and Y scroll feature?
I just want it to slide inside the event div with a margin left that is as long as the user column. Don't know how though. Maybe not a good solution? 
I would attached some code but I have no idea how to approach this problem yet.

I did a "illustration" of the problem, hopefully that brings some clarity.
The first two rows is describing what it looks like now, the last two rows is describing what I want to achieve.

Using in this project:
jQuery,
JQuery DataTables,
AngularJS

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/fDyE2/3/

HTML

```
<div class="user">
    <p>User</p>
</div>
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="event">
        <p class="title">Event 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
.user, .timeline {
    border:#000 dashed 1px;
    float:left;
}
.user {
    padding:17px 25px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.timeline {
    padding:5px;
    width:400px;
    overflow:auto;
    height:76px;
}
.event {
    padding:5px;
    background:orange;
    width:800px;
    height:51px;
}
```

Jquery

```
    $(ducument).ready(function(){
    var title = $(".title"),
    target = $(".event").offset().left;
setInterval(function () {
    if ($(".timeline").scrollLeft() > target) {
        title.css({
            "position": "fixed",
                "top": (title.closest(".event").offset().top + 5) +"px",
                "left": title.closest(".event").offset().right + "px"
        });
    } else {
        title.css({
            "position": "static",
                "top": "auto",
                "left": "auto"
        });
    }
}, 100);
    });
```

Comment: Thx Mayank, that seems to do the trick! I´ll try it and come back to you.